# php substr_count on an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can you use substr_count to count each element in an array's occurance in another array?

```
i.e. $urls = array (
'www.thesun.co.uk',
'www.bbcnews.co.uk',
);

$names = array (
'rex kum',
'tony blair', 
);
```

so if i wanted to use substr_count to count the occurance of the name rex kumi on the sun webpage, how would this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this a lot I'd put it in a function but:

```
 foreach($names as $name)
 {
       foreach($urls as $url)
      {
           print "Count for $name and $url is: " . substr_count($url, $name);
      }
 }
```

The question that you asked (counting the instances of one array in another array) is different from what you actually asked (count the instances of one array, on a web site).  You actually want a combination of my answer and the answer mentioned where you load the contents of the website. (Use nested foreach loops)

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're missing the php basics, but what the hack. You'll use function nested foreach loop:

```
$results = array();
foreach( $urls as $url){
    foreach( $names as $key => $name){
        if( !isset( $results[$key])){
           $results[$key] = 0; // you better initialize elements in separate foreach loop
        }

        // Strtolower because name may be capitalized, uppercased and so on
        $content = strtolower( file_get_contents( $url));
        $results[$key] += substr_count( $content, strtolower( $name));
    }
}
```